# After working for while http post leads to: getaddrinfo EADDRINFO

Tags: node.js, http

I have a nodejs code posting data on localhost via a HTTP while testing I find that once the connection counts to 1024 it starts giving the following error:

```
getaddrinfo EADDRINFO
```

I have increased the max connection limited and tested HTTP server by making more connection while I am getting this error via node code using `curl` which is able to makes connection without any failure.

Here is the code snippet which is posting data:

```
function post(message, domain, callback){
        var self=this;
        var json = JSON.stringify(message);
        var p = url.parse(domain);
        var headers = {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Content-Length': json.length
        };

        console.log('hostname: ' + p.hostname);
        var options = {
            host: p.hostname,
            port: p.port,
            path: p.pathname,
            method: 'POST',
            headers: headers
        };

        var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
            res.setEncoding('utf-8');
            var responseString = '';
            res.on('data', function(data) {
                responseString += data;
            });

            res.on('end', function() {
                logger.info(responseString);
                self.responseQ.push(responseString);
                callback(self,message,'success');
            });
        });

        req.on('error', function(e) {
            //TODO: handle error.
            logger.error('[e] Error while posting: '+e);
            callback(self, message,'failure');
        });
        logger.info("post: "+json);
        req.write(json);
        req.end();

    }
```

I thought there might be some issue with (even though I was using localhost) I tried replacing `host` with IP Address; then after working for 2 minutes same code started giving the following error in the similar fashion:

```
Error: connect EMFILE
```

What might be causing the code to break in between ?

Any help will be appreciated thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying out multiple options I found the following reasons that may cause this issue:

1. If you are using domain names (DNS might be a issue)
2. max file limit on your process.

In my case specifically cause of the failure was case 2; in which case the max limit of files that my nodejs process can open was limited upto `1024` while the webserver can accept more connection.

All needed in such cases is to change the limit.

1. Check the limits for your user:

   `$su - username
   $ulimit -Hn 
   $ulimit -Sn`
2. Change the values as per your needs:

   `vi /etc/security/limits.conf`

add the following lines

```
username soft nofile 4096
username hard nofile 10240
```

3. Change system wide limit on open-files:

   vi /etc/sysctl.conf

add the following line

```
fs.file-max = 100000
```

4. Finally check your changes by repeating step 1 to ensure all the changes done are applied correctly.